# Connecting front-end and back-end ( spring mvc )using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

[image: My Code]

I'm trying to connect front-end and the back-end(REST) (Spring MVC) of my applicationJEE, the problem is with the current code on app.js and RestUserController.java I can reach my REST side ( I use :

```
var res = $http.post('/myproject/rest/saveUser', {params: { firstname : $scope.user.firstname}}) )
```

but the `firstname` is always NULL, can anyone help me please, I'm stuck here !

Comment: Can you provide code of your javascript code?

Comment: With Post Method you can't get param, the Post Method can has Data